# Why is my .Net Core MVC service returning 200s for non-existent routes?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .net core MVC Web API project (or whatever it's called in .net core now). I have a Message Controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")
public class MessageController
{
    Public MessageController()
    {}

    // This works
    [HttpGet]
    public IMessage Get()
    {
        // Do stuff to get a Message
        return Message;
    }
}
```

When I call the Get endpoint like so:

```
GET => http://MyService/api/Message/
```

I get back the expected message object as JSON and an HTTP 200.

However, when I call a nonexistent endpoint:

```
GET => http://MyService/api/Message/Foo
```

I get back empty json `[]` and an HTTP 200.

Obviously something in the routing is matching on every route and returning 200 rather than matching only on actual routes and returning 404s for anything that doesn't match. So where is the default route which is catching everything defined and how do I kill it?

Comment: check in the `Configure` method in `Startup.cs` file for `app.UseMvc(routes =>.........`. Maybe you are using a tutorial or something and it has some routes defined there?

Comment: Yeah, thought of that. My startup has `app.UseMvc();`

Comment: Post the whole startup/configure method. We dunno if and which middleware you are using